# Angular date error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

In AngularJS I'm trying to use the Date() function to get milliseconds from

```
'2014-11-19 10:58:16'
```

With this function

```
var n = new Date.parse('2014-11-19 10:58:16');
```

But I'm getting a weird error

```
TypeError: function parse() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `new` in this context? (This does not have much to do with Angular, by the way.)

Comment: That just totally fixed it! I thought, because of the error, it had  something to do with AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frédéric Hamidi posted in the comment I shouldn't have used

```
new Date
```

but

```
Date
```

Thank you [Frédéric Hamidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi)